# Completely remove Qt environment?

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

How to completely remove Qt environment?

I installed Qt Creator Integrated Development from the Ubuntu Software Center,then I compiled and installed Qt 4.8.6 .There were few errors when I try to compile an Application.

I  Uninstalled / Removed via the Ubuntu Software Center.

But when I tried to install QT 5.3 I can see the Qt 4.8 kit and recently accessed files.

What should I do if I want to completely remove the Qt in my system? I want to uninstall all the 4.8.6 and , then try to reinstall the 5.3.

Comment: Isn't this a better question for the Ubuntu SE or for Superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kit information is stored in Qt Creator's preferences in your user profile. It has nothing to do with whether a given version of Qt is actually installed. You have to manually remove the kit *and* the qt version from your Qt Creator settings, it doesn't randomly mess with your own preferences :)